# Django dynamic url path from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Django with some fluency in Python, primarily Pandas. I'm trying to build dynamic paths for my app, such that a user pressing a button will reference my pandas dataframe, either by index or some primary key, in order to have a unique page for each row in my dataset. More specifically I'm generating a random number to select a random row from my dataframe.

I understand and have read the documentation for Django's URL dispatcher but I'm only aware of setting custom paths that can be referenced in the html by the user typing in their path and not necessarily an automated version of that.

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is to achieve a similar result to https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ with "/title/" as my app name and "/tt0111161/" as the custom path from my primary key/index/random number of my dataframe row.

I've tried various versions of this method. The views.py looks like this:

```
def all(request, id):
    random_number = random.randint(0,100)
    row = df.iloc[random_number]
    id = random_number
    return render(request, "play/all.html", {
        "title": row['title'],
        "year": row['year'],
    })
```

The urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("all/<int:id>/", views.all, name="all"),
]
```

I just can't figure out how to make this functional. Is it even possible for Django to automate and dynamically update its path to reflect a certain path without creating a specific path for every single row in a dataframe? In the IMDb example, if IMDb had a dataframe with primary keys, how would they go about creating unique and dynamic paths for each datapoint?